# current_user nil after successful sign_in while using mongoid and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, omniauth

for context, i'm using devise 3.4.1, mongoid 4.0.0, rails 4.1.7

when i sign in (successfully), i am redirected to the root path as dictated by my after_sign_in_path_for. from here, i assume my user is signed in. however, once i navigate to another page that references current_user in a controller method, i get an error like so:

```
undefined method `searches' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
@current_search = current_user.searches.build

if(params[:role].present?)
  @current_search.add_condition(role: "#{params[:role]}")
```

to try to further understand the problem i debugged the session and everything seems to be okay:

```
{"session_id"=>"bbae2e07d3d3e506ad662410b23cefb7",    
"warden.user.user.key"=>[["54f787e0636c612b75ba0000"], 
"$2a$10$xvDkF6vFs.bHAa3rjsvPR."], 
"flash"=>{"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"Signed in 
successfully."}}, 
"_csrf_token"=>"/OVXffT6+er8OipE47/gOs0w9mbK9s/XqgwFOyiSumA="}
```

some other's who seemed to have a similar problem seemed to just be able to fix it with a call to `before_action :authenticate_user!`, but in my case it just generates a `401 Unauthorized` error and redirects the user to the login page again with the dialog of `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

Comment: Just to be sure - when creating your `Devise` model, did you do `rails generate devise user`? Or maybe you have created something else, eg. `member`?

Comment: yes @PawełDawczak. my user model is called user and i used the standard generator.

Comment: Could you add to your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` code `<%= p current_user.inspect %>`? This will render what is returned from `current_user` with each request. When having that code - try log in to your application. In place where you put the provided code, `nil` should be changed to something similar to your `User`. After logging in, try to navigate to problematic pages, and you'll be able to quickly validate if, and when the `current_user` stopped working. This will help narrow down the problem. Good luck!

Comment: appreciate the suggestion @PawełDawczak! unfortunately it's rendering nil on **any** page i navigate to, in spite of the session seeming to be valid as mentioned previously

Comment: To be hones - I haven't try any project with mongoid + devise, and unfortunately - I don't have any ideas out of my head... Well, your problem is great opportunity, to create a project and try! We'll figure that out!

Comment: Could you provide how did you overwrote `after_sign_in_path_for`? Or any other modifications you've applied, so I can reproduce locally? That would help!

Comment: I have just run in problem with MongoID and Devise - could you try modify your `app/models/user.rb` as described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2949#issuecomment-42453850)? With this applied it seems to work. Give it a shot!

Comment: @PawełDawczak, yeah i've applied the serialization hack. unfortunately my problem is a different one

Comment: my after_sign_in_path_for is the same as described in the documentation:  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end

Comment: actually @paweldawczak, the problem/solution lied in the hack... so for awhile i'd be using `def self.serialize_from_session(key, salt)
    record = to_adapter.get(key[0]["$oid"])
    record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
  end`, but i had to replace it with `def self.serialize_into_session(record)
    [record.id.to_s, record.authenticatable_salt]
end` .... would love to understand what's going on here

Comment: That's really great news in the morning (at least for me :))!

Comment: @PawełDawczak :) so actually i discovered no hack is necessary at all now. mongoid must have fixed this issue in a recent release and i didn't realize..

Comment: Hey! Thanks for sharing the information! Just a quick question - did you have a problem with *standard* way of logging in, or with *OAuth* authorization? In one of your comments I've seen `request.env['omniauth.origin']`. It might be helpful to at least know what to expect :). Again - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem/solution lied in the hack... so for awhile i'd been using this successfully:

```
def self.serialize_from_session(key, salt)
  record = to_adapter.get(key[0]["$oid"])
  record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
end
```

but i had to replace it with

```
def self.serialize_into_session(record)
  [record.id.to_s, record.authenticatable_salt]
end
```

.... would love to better understand what's going on here if someone can explain

**// UPDATE**

**Actually, the hack is no longer necessary at all now. I think the issue must've been fixed by the mongoid team.**

Comment: Yes, if you use latest mongoid version  ~> '4.0.2', we don't need this hack anymore but vice versa have to remove it to prevent bugs.